# Removing Current value from <Select> dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 Dropdown boxes that allows users to select their Age and Gender.These Dropdown boxes draw their value from my database(PHP 5.5+ MYSQL), and use the retrieved value as the default value shown to the user.

The dropbox's other options are generated by means of functions that run on pageload.

The functions are:

```
function AgeDropDown(){
    var list= document.getElementById("Age");
    for(var i=1;i<100;i++)
    {
        var opt = document.createElement("option");
        opt.value= i;
        opt.textContent=i;
        list.appendChild(opt);
    }
```

}

```
function genderlist(){
    var list= document.getElementById("Gender");
    var choices=["M","F"];
    for(i=0;i<choices.length;i++)
    {
        var opt = document.createElement("option");
        opt.value= choices[i];
        opt.textContent=choices[i];
        list.appendChild(opt);
    }
}
```

While my code works perfectly, and the options are all displayed, whenever i click on the dropbox to change the value, the current value is shown **in addition** to the generated options.

E.g

Age

```
18   
1
2
3    <---- Values shown in the select dropdown
4
5
6
```

Gender

```
M
M
F
```

How would i go about removing the default value from the options shown when the dropdown box is clicked?

E.g(What i want to happen instead of what is shown above.)

Age

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
```

Gender

```
M
F
```

Comment: Default value in the sense? You wanted to remove the value which is selected already on click?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you have to do is empty the div. You can set the innerHTML to empty string to empty the div.

**Note:**

What you are tyring to do is adding/appending elements to your div. So you have to clear the div ( remove its children).

The code should be `list.innerHTML = "";`

The complete code should be as below:

```
function AgeDropDown(){
    var list= document.getElementById("Age");
    list.innerHTML = "";
    for(var i=1;i<100;i++)
    {
        var opt = document.createElement("option");
        opt.value= i;
        opt.textContent=i;
        list.appendChild(opt);
    }

}

function genderlist(){
    var list= document.getElementById("Gender");
    list.innerHTML = "";
    var choices=["M","F"];
    for(i=0;i<choices.length;i++)
    {
        var opt = document.createElement("option");
        opt.value= choices[i];
        opt.textContent=choices[i];
        list.appendChild(opt);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the first element of your list using jQuery like this:

```
$('#Gender').find('option').first().remove();
```

Or:

```
$('#Age').find('option').first().remove();
```